# Watch and expression must have a pointer

Tags: visual-c++

```
auto_ptr<MoistAir> ma(new MoistAir);

L1->setPabs(Pabs);
L1->setQm(qm2);
L1->setT(t1);
L1->setX(x1);

if ((L2->getQm() / L3->getQm()) > 1)   
    w = L3->getQm() / (A0 * 1.2);  
  else   
    w = L2->getQm() / (A0 * 1.2);

//This is a function i tried to add watch on
double MoistAir::getQm()
{
  return Fqm;
}
```

[image: Debugger VS] 
I tries to add watch on the function in visual studio to get the result? Is it possible. Do i have to introduce a variable or step in to the function? I just want to mark the code as in C# and get value.

If i step in to then function i can see the result.

Comment: Can you show us how you declare `L2` and `L3`?

Comment: Sorry. I have made the clearer sample. In C# I can mark a part of the code to get the result. The code is working it's just me that learn to navigate around in c/c++ and Mollierdiagram code.

Answer (score 8):

After some more reading/talking to person programming C/C++ told me how to do. maybe it's can help somebody else.

```
((L2)._Myptr)->getQm()  2.3999999756939365  double
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case the object was a Shared_ptr, I used ((&Shared_PtrObj)->_Ptr)->objMethod(). This solved my issue and showed the exact output on watch window.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the variable is not getting any value. Try checking the return value of `L3->getQm()` by create a new variable and assigning it the result of  `L3->getQm()`.

I'm not very sure if your if-statement is correct, but in my experience, when I have two conditions in the same if-statement I usually use `||` or `&&` depending on what I want.

Good luck with your app.

Comment: I think the OP is doing division between the results of `getQm()` of `L2` and `L3` and checking if the result of the division is greater than 1. Either way, I don't think this really answer the question, maybe `L2` and `L3` need to be declared differently? The OP really hasn't supplied enough code probably.